Help debugging a chicken coop door problem
(I am not even a noob in electronics so please be a bit patient).
I had purchased this automatic chicken coop door which within 3 months stopped working.
(the open button would not open the door. Neither setting the timer for it to open was doing something). However, closing works.
I decided to try and find out what is the problem. I am attaching an image of the circuit. When I opened it there was definitely some water inside (not a great construction overall).

BDR6121b datasheet (chinese)
STC8H1k28 datasheet
Highlighted are the DC motor controller which seems to be a BDR6121b from Bardeen Micro and the main chip which is an STC8H1k28 from STC. I have followed the signal from the switch when it is pressed to pin 25 (top left in the image) of the STC. So when the switch is pressed I measure +3 V on pin 25 of the STC.
I have also managed to measure voltage at both input pins of the BDR6121 (pin 2, 3 bottom middle ones in the picture). From the datasheet is seems they are expecting some PWM signal on both that controls the way the motor will turn. By connecting one or the other of the input pins of the BDR to constant voltage I got the motor rotate both ways (so it seems this works?).
Therefore it seems that either the STC firmware is not behaving correctly anymore, or something in the path from the STC to the DC motor controller is failing?. Tools at my disposal are pretty basic. multimeter + buspirate + soldering station.
My questions to you experts are:
a) Should I even bother? Maybe I should just salvage some parts and try to build something simple with an Arduino?
b) If yes, what next steps would you take trying to fix this?
Thank you all!

wash the board with isopropyl alcohol ... blow out the excess ... allow to dry and test again

Use 91% isoprop. And make sure there's no added oils. Just water.

It’s not a ST microcontroller!  It’s made by the Chinese company STC.

If there's been a short caused by water, then any part could be broken. Including one part of the MCU - it's common that one hardware peripheral inside the MCU dies but that the rest of it keeps working - usually it's some internal protection diode that has been fried. However, you can usually spot water/moisture damage looking like white, dusty remains on the PCB.

@Kartman thanks for the correction. i edited the question.
Also thank you all for the commments. i will try the isoprop solution now and report back.

Hey all. Sadly it didn't work. Thank you for the suggestions. I think I will scavenge what I can from it and try to build my own with an arduino.
